# Ellipse Perimeter

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

I've seen lots of methods of getting an approximation of the perimeter of an ellipse, however, I was wondering if there is an exact method that exists, no matter how complex.

Comment: There's a reason it is approximated; the type of calculation required is sometimes called an "elliptic integral".

Comment: You can read: http://www.rowan.edu/colleges/csm/departments/math/facultystaff/osler/125%20The%20Perimeter%20of%20an%20Ellipse%20as%20in%20Math%20Sci.pdf

Comment: @EmilioNovati thanks. Not to sound ungrateful, however, I was more looking for a "yes, it is possible to calculate the exact perimeter of an ellipse" or "no, it is impossible to calculate the exact perimeter of an ellipse"

Comment: To expand on abiessu's useful comment, of course a function describing the perimeter exists, but it is not a composition of elementary functions, and so generically (that is, for most parameter values), it is not possible to express the perimeter in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: In some sense, the question is really about what you mean by "calculating the exact perimeter" than about ellipses per se.

Comment: @Travis Ok thanks

Comment: @Travis What I mean is, given center, vertex and co-vertex, is there a method or formula to calculate the perimeter of that ellipse.

Comment: ( Not remembering it exactly, something like $2 \pi a E(\epsilon) $. The question has been asked and answered many times.

Comment: @Narasimham I'm sure it has. I'm more looking for a "yes, it is possible to calculate the exact perimeter of an ellipse" or "no, it is impossible to calculate the exact perimeter of an ellipse" using "number-line values"

Comment: The perimeter is intrinsic, it is expressible in terms of $ a,b $. The cloth is given, tailor should handle the first part.Elliptic integrals like other functions  are very accurately expressed.

Comment: @NioPullus What do you mean by "using number line values"? I don't think this is a common term. Again, this question really hinges on what you mean by "calculate".

Comment: @Travis It's not a very technical term but what I mean by a number line value is a real number, essentially.

Comment: Well, the perimeter of an ellipse given by certain parameters is certainly a real number, and one can express it in terms of, for example, the elliptic integral functions that Brevan mentions in his good answer. (See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral ) If one is happy with such a representation, the answer to your question is certainly yes. For general parameter values, though, this expression *cannot* be written in terms of elementary functions alone.

Comment: @Travis ok that's what I was wondering. Thanks

Comment: The perimeter of an ellipse is $(a+b)\pi$, and its surface is $ab\pi$. In the case of a circle, we have $a=b=r$. But you probably meant evaluating a random arc length or area sector, whose formulas, for circles, have elementary expressions, but in the more general case, that of an ellipse, do not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, such a function exists. It is called the [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral). Given some basic information about the ellipse one can find an analytic form using the integral. However, there is no way to express the answer (in general) using [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). Using the integrals requires the arc length formula, generally taught in a first or second year calculus course.

Edit: I should note that the formula requires a modular angle and the eccentricity of the ellipse, both of which can be found using the information you say you have... just expect to get a really complicated form if you go around using the formula with arbitrary numbers (only special cases will simplify... see the first few paragraphs of the Wikipedia page for a deeper explanation of this)

Comment: So just to be clear, there is no possible way to express the perimeter of an ellipse with given parameters using "number-line values"?

Comment: Not necessarily. Remember that circles are an example of an ellipse where the major and minor axes are equal. The perimeter (more formally called arc length) of a circle is $2\pi r$. If the radius is $\frac{1}{\pi}$ then the arc length is $2$. This same logic holds for ellipses, and (as I added in my answer), you can find more about this on the first few paragraphs of the page on elliptic integrals

Comment: Ok, so it's sometimes possible to express the perimeter of an ellipse with given parameters using "number-line values", but not always, if I understand the situation correctly.

Comment: @NioPullus Exactly. (Note that "number line values" are called integers in mathematics)

Comment: Alright thanks, that's the answer I was looking for. I don't know if I would equate "number line values" to integers since I could surely draw 2.5 on a number line, however, I wouldn't call 2.5 an integer.

Comment: Well then you can put any elliptical perimeter on the number line...

Comment: @NioPullus If you are defining the number line as containing all real numbers, then yes - all elliptical arc lengths can be expressed. But only if you are including all real numbers (such as $\pi$). You need to be more specific than "number line values" - that phrase makes little sense to a mathematician.

Comment: What I was really looking for when I asked this question is: Can I plug in a width and a height for an ellipse and get its perimeter expressed in numerical form? I haven't studied Integral Calculus yet so I am not too familiar with how this process works but really what I am wondering is if I can get a numerical value as the result.

Comment: if you are simply searching for a numerical answer, then yes - you can get the answer for any ellipse. It might be an answer like $0.9371174641072...$ (or any other real number), but you can absolutely get any numerical value to arbitrary precision. Working with elliptical integrals is not easy though, and does require some calculus to get to the final equation where you can plug in values.